# Azure Database automated export to local machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to make an automated backup of an Azure Database. I don’t want use Azures build in point in time restore. My plan was something like making an automated export to an Azure storage blob and download it daily from there. But since MS dropped the automated export function (01.03.2017) that fell apart. Is there still a way to do this or maybe a better approach? Basically my goal is to get a local automated backup from my Azure Database so I can restore it without needing to rely on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

> My plan was something like making an automated export to an Azure storage blob and download it daily from there. But since MS dropped the automated export function (01.03.2017) that fell apart. Is there still a way to do this or maybe a better approach?

Firstly, as you said, Azure SQL Database [Automated Export is retired](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export) on March 1, 2017, now we could use long-term backup retention or Azure Automation to archive SQL databases, and database backups are stored in an **Azure Recovery Services vault** instead of Azure storage Blob, the Recovery services vault seems not enable us to download database backups to local machine.

Secondly, [Azure SQL Database REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/) do not provide operations for backup and export Azure SQL Database to Azure storage or local machine.

Thirdly, we could create a maintenance plan to backup database in SQL Server Management Studio,  but it does not enable us to create a maintenance plan to schedule and automate backup **Azure SQL**.

I suspect it does not enable to backup Azure SQL Database to our local machine currently.

Comment: If it is ok with you @Fred I will not accept your answer so that it stays unanswered for the future. If you insist I would accept it because it is technically the right answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Automation Account to schedule Azure DB export to Azure Storage
 see [tutorial here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/02/07/automate-export-azure-sql-db-to-blob-storage-use-automation-account/)